# 960 grid, img problem

Tags: css-float, 960.gs

recently downloaded the 960 grid system to play around with.

Now the problem im having is that the image is not coming across to the left after the singer songwriter tag is closed off. Both columns before the image add up to 12 exactly

The following code should display a logo image up top, singer songwriter description to the right of it. Then on a new line i should see image placeholder in gray and a paragraph of text to the write of that. However it is currently mixed up

Can anybody advise me if i need to change anything to accommodate images

heres a link to the page http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/alice
and heres a link to how i basically want it to flow http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/alice/img/960img.gif

**Page code**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/960.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/text.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />

       <title></title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container_12">
<div class="grid_5"> <img src="img/namelogo.png" alt="#" /></div>
<div class="grid_7"> Singer/Songwriter</div>
<div class="grid_5"> <img src="img/img.jpg" alt="#" /></div>
<div class="grid_7"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan nunc vel odio faucibus euismod. Nulla semper lorem vel risus volutpat congue. Sed eleifend velit eget mauris luctus in imperdiet eros ultricies. Ut et gravida ligula. Vestibulum placerat placerat bibendum. Vestibulum pretium mollis arcu, et pharetra est sagittis sed. Vestibulum facilisis elementum urna vel fermentum. Vestibulum id metus at magna tristique ornare in id lorem. Nulla rhoncus, neque ac scelerisque varius, felis enim convallis ipsum, sed auctor libero dolor in ligula. Vivamus rhoncus, sapien non feugiat tempus, tortor enim euismod dolor, ac placerat ante enim sed diam. </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the second grid 5 should be seperated on a new row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Put your reset before 960.css and then add a clear after the first line.

## [click here to See example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JmWQj/)

Here's my code:

```
<div class="grid_5"> <img src="http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/alice/img/namelogo.png" alt="#" /></div>
<div class="grid_7"> Singer/Songwriter</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="grid_5"> <img src="http://digitalgenesis.com.au/sites/alice/img/img.jpg" alt="#" /></div>
<div class="grid_7"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan nunc vel odio faucibus euismod. Nulla semper lorem vel risus volutpat congue. Sed eleifend velit eget mauris luctus in imperdiet eros ultricies. Ut et gravida ligula. Vestibulum placerat placerat bibendum. Vestibulum pretium mollis arcu, et pharetra est sagittis sed. Vestibulum facilisis elementum urna vel fermentum. Vestibulum id metus at magna tristique ornare in id lorem. Nulla rhoncus, neque ac scelerisque varius, felis enim convallis ipsum, sed auctor libero dolor in ligula. Vivamus rhoncus, sapien non feugiat tempus, tortor enim euismod dolor, ac placerat ante enim sed diam. </div>
```

Comment: nar didnt work, i think stoosh was right the first comment he posted. i tryed <div style="clear:both;"></div> between singer/songwriter and the start of the next image tag. fixed it up. However i thought it was ment to clear automatically with grids, if anybody can recommend a better method let me know, cheers for responses guys

Comment: ah, cheers for that update. i ment the reset file didnt change much itself being put as first link rel. but yer clear div works. obviously the 960 grid system doesnt clear floats itself

Comment: Well it doesn't clear itself, but what happens is normally your divs are somewhat equal in height so they match up and it sits correctly. The way i've shown you is the most correct. clearfix below is actually not the right method, clearfix is for a div that contains a bunch of floated elements, it would go on the parent div, not on the clearing div.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `clearfix` class to drop the next set of divs down

```
<div class="container_12">
<div class="grid_5"> <img src="img/namelogo.png" alt="#" /></div>
<div class="grid_7"> Singer/Songwriter</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="grid_5"> <img src="img/img.jpg" alt="#" /></div>
<div class="grid_7"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: alternatively i could give the image after singer/songwriter an extra div class i suppose, and add the clearfix in css via its 2nd class name